# No such customer: cus_************ (Stripe::InvalidRequestError) when customer exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I am working on an E-Commerce market place called foodsy. I am using `stripe connect` for the purpose. Connected accounts are created using `stripe-connect-omniauth`. And foodsy has several customers. An order for an `Sku` is created in rails controller by

```
 Stripe.api_key = "sk_test_************"
    Stripe::Order.create(
      {:currency => 'usd',
      :items => [
        {
          :type => 'sku',
          :parent => "sku_************"
        }
      ] },
    {  :stripe_account => "acct_************" }
    )
```

It creates an order with id  `or_************` .

The customer who exist on the foodsy platform buys it ,

```
order=Stripe::Order.retrieve("or_************",stripe_account: "acct_************")
order.pay(customer: "cus_************")
```

But this code returns an error `No such customer: cus_************ (Stripe::InvalidRequestError).`

The customer exist as I can see him on dashboard and source attribute is set on stripe. So why is it going wrong ?

Comment: For anybody searching by the error message: Make sure you use the proper API key and secret.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The problem is that the customer exists on the platform's account, but not on the connected account you're trying to create the charge on.

You need to [share the customer](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/shared-customers) from the platform account to the connected account:

```
# Create a token from the customer on the platform account
token = Stripe::Token.create(
  {:customer => "cus_7QLGXg0dkUYWmK"},
  {:stripe_account => "acct_17BTxDCioT3wKMvR"}
)

# Retrieve the order on the connected account and pay it using the token
order = Stripe::Order.retrieve("or_17BUNHCioT3wKMvREWdDBagG",
  stripe_account: "acct_17BTxDCioT3wKMvR"
)
order.pay(source: token.id)
```

Comment: Ok.. That solved the problem. The documentation is quite messed up. It seems they had documented it.. But I couldnt find the links in the stripe-connect documentation, but its their in the stripe-api documentation. 

[https://stripe.com/docs/connect/shared-customers]

Answer (score 8):

This can also happen if you use the wrong APiKey